# Pandas Dataframe convert column of lists to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert a dataframe that has list of various size for example something like this:

```
d={'A':[1,2,3],'B':[[1,2,3],[3,5],[4]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

to something like this:

```
d1={'A':[1,2,3],'B-1':[1,0,0],'B-2':[1,0,0],'B-3':[1,1,0],'B-4':[0,0,1],'B-5':[0,1,0]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
df1
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`explode` the lists then `get_dummies` and `sum` over the original index. (`max` [credit to @JonClements] if you want true dummies and not counts in case there can be multiples). Then join the result back

```
dfB = pd.get_dummies(df['B'].explode()).sum(level=0).add_prefix('B-')
#dfB = pd.get_dummies(df['B'].explode()).max(level=0).add_prefix('B-')

df = pd.concat([df['A'], dfB], axis=1)

#   A  B-1  B-2  B-3  B-4  B-5
#0  1    1    1    1    0    0
#1  2    0    0    1    0    1
#2  3    0    0    0    1    0
```

---

You can use `pop` to remove the column you explode so you don't need to specify `df[list_of_all_columns_except_B]` in the concat:

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df.pop('B').explode()).sum(level=0).add_prefix('B-')],
                axis=1)
```